# How to open "Connecting to a service" windows and authenticate website?

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-store

On some Windows 8.1 and Windows Universal app, when login to some service (Google, Facebook, Twitch, ...) I see this window open and login box like this. I search with google but no help to find how to implement on my app.

Can anyone give me answer or link to this function?

[image: Connecting to serrvice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `WebAuthenticationBroker` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx)